# What is Android Permission WRITE_GSERVICES exactly for?

Tags: android, permissions

My application complains about not having this permission. I´m doing contact manipulation and I´m not sure what the problem is.

The documentation says "Allows an application to modify the Google service map."

What Google service map? I don´t use any Google services right now.

Comment: Google says: "Not for use by third-party applications", you're most likely trying to modify something you're not supposed to. What you want is to access the content provider for contacts, see link here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html

Comment: I don´t want to acces the content provider, because I do it already. But thank you anyway

Comment: Please post the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

It allows an application to modify the Google service map.

For more about google service maps refer to [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/)

Comment: I don't see that term mentioned anywhere in those links and you're not providing an answer...